# How can I set up a correct format while doing new Date() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a date in a following format:

```
12/11/2015 07:12 PM
```

In jQuery I'm doing:

```
var parsedDate2 = new Date(date);
alert(parsedDate2);
```

And that prints me:

```
Fri Dec 11 2015 07:12:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

and that almost works correctly, mostly because in my example (`12/11/2015 07:12 PM`) the format is `DD/MM` and not `MM/DD`. However, jQuery treats it as the month is first. That's a problem, because when I chose as input:

```
19/11/2015 07:17 PM  <--- (19th of November)
```

I'm getting:

```
Invalid date
```

So how can I set up the correct format here with the day before the month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugly, but it work, with JS only :

```
a = "12/11/2015  07:12 PM";
b = a.split(' ');
c = b[0].split('/');

bad = new Date(a);
alert('bad : '+bad);
good = new Date(c[1]+'/'+c[0]+'/'+c[2]+' '+b[1]+' '+b[2]);
alert('good : '+good);
```

The other way is to use [Moment.js parsing tool](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Comment: can you give me a hint of how to use moment.js in my particular example?

Comment: `var date_in_my_mad_format = "55:12 12/2014/31";`

`var realdate = moment(date_in_my_mad_format, "mm:hh MM/YYYY/DD");`
    var myoutdate = realdate.format("YYYY-DD-MM hh:mm");
    // myoutdate == 2014-12-31 12:55`

Comment: Yes, I'm with @ФагимСадыков take a look at http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/ ; a lot of helpfull stuff ;)

Answer (score 1):

Think that you should use more specialized and focused library along with JQuery, for me the best one is [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) - it has all and more than needed to date-time parsing and formatting and doesn't do something else.

Also, there are some other alternatives, like `date.js` and `globalize.js`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of date.js, I checked it out and looks useful!

Answer (score 0):

It's in the form of `mm/dd/yyyy`. Try `11/19/2015 07:17 PM`. Sadly, jQuery doesn't know which format you're using and so, uses the deafult one.

Comment: I cannot change my date format due to heavy usage in different place, that's why I wanted to change the way of how `new Date()` works in this particular case - is there a way of setting the date time format here?

Comment: You can, maybe, write a global function to change its format?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Javascript Date system isn't very malleable when it comes to adding date formats. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) is a reference from Mozilla. I think [wierdpanda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3102854/weirdpanda) has the right idea, write a function that accepts your date format, reformats it before feeding it to `new Date()`, and returns the result. Use this in place of where you have `new Date()`, and all should be good.